# How to use transaction correctly in mongoose with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm developing a backend using Node.js, TypeScript, Express.js, and Mongoose. I want to use transactions in my project, but I'm facing an issue I can't resolve.

Here's the endpoint where I want to use a transaction:

```
const addReminder = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> => {
  const currentUserId = req.currentUser?.id;
  const { title, description, reminderDate, receivers, relatedObjectId } = req.body;

  const result = await TransactionService.performTransaction(async () => {
    const task = await Task.findById(relatedObjectId).select('_id').lean().exec();
    const unsuitability = await Unsuitability.findById(relatedObjectId).select('_id').lean().exec();

    if (!task && !unsuitability) {
      throw new NotFoundError();
    }

    const reminder = new Reminder({
      relatedObjectId,
      title,
      description,
      reminderDate,
      receivers,
      createdBy: currentUserId,
    });
    await reminder.save();

    const jobName = reminder._id.toString() + title;
    await CronService.addReminder(reminder, jobName);

    return reminder;
  });

  res.status(201).send({
    summary: InformationMessage.SUCCESS,
    detail: InformationMessage.REMINDER_ADDED,
    severity: 'success',
    result,
  });
};
```

Here's my TransactionService:

```
export class TransactionService {
  static async performTransaction(fn: (session: mongoose.ClientSession) => Promise<any>): Promise<any> {
    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();

    try {
      const result = await fn(session);

      await session.commitTransaction();
      session.endSession();

      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      await session.abortTransaction();
      session.endSession();
      logger.error('Transaction error!: ', error);
      throw new Error('Transaction error!');
    }
  }
}
```

And here's my CronService.addReminder() function:

```
static async addReminder(reminder: IReminder, jobName: string) {
    const mailBody = setMailParameters(reminder);
    const { reminderDate } = reminder;
    const now = new Date();

    if (reminderDate <= now) {
      throw new BadRequestError(ErrorMessage.ERROR, ErrorMessage.INVALID_DATE);
    }
    
    const newJob = new cron.CronJob(reminderDate, async () => {
      try {
        scheduleReminder(mailBody, jobName);

        this.deleteReminder(jobName);
        newJob.stop();
      } catch (error) {
        logger.error(FAILED_TO_CREATE_MAIL_CONTENT);
      }
    });

    this.cronJobs[jobName] = newJob;
    newJob.start();

    logger.info(`Reminder job "${jobName}" scheduled for ${reminder.reminderDate}`);
  }
```

I have an endpoint, and within it, I'm running a function named CronService.addReminder(). Additionally, I've created a TransactionService.

In this scenario, I want to use transactions in the operations performed within the endpoint. When I make a request to the endpoint with a `reminderDate` set to a past date, I get an error, but the rollback operation doesn't occur.

I tried to perform date validation somewhere before saving the reminder, but in that case, my errors were thrown in a general form as `'Transaction error!'`.

Rollback function not working.

Even if I manage to handle the error throw part, the rollback operation doesn't take place when an error occurs inside the `addReminder()` function. What should I do in this scenario, and what's the correct way to solve this problem?